# Problem with mathring and subscripts

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to use \mathring with a subscript and a superscript. I try

```
{{ \mathring {\omega}}^{ab}}_{\mu}
```

where I have put

```
{ \mathring {\omega}}^{ab}
```

in an extra set of parentheses 
in the hope that the mu will be set to the right of the 'ab', but it comes out underneath it. I can make things work by using

```
{ \mathring {\omega}^{ab}}_{\phantom{ab}\mu}
```

but this seems rather clumsy. Why is the usual trick for index spacing not working?  Is there a neater way to get what I want?

my preamble starts with

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems fine, but if you want, just set the subscript with a separate `{}_{\mu}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

${{ \mathring {\omega}}^{ab}}_{\mu} \quad
 \mathring {\omega}^{ab} {}_{\mu}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add an empty group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\mathring{\omega}^{ab}_{\mu}$\qquad
${{}\mathring{\omega}^{ab}}_{\mu}$\qquad

\end{document}
```

[image]